# compressing HDF5 files in Mathematica

Tags: compression, export, wolfram-mathematica, hdf5

I am working with Mathematica 9 and exporting huge lists (a typical list will have dimensions of 182500,4,8,42). Each file has about 6 lists of this size (all integers, not sure if this makes a difference in lists, I know it do in other array types, anyway). Saving them is HDF5 format successfully, however, the size of the files is relatively large (1.5 GB).

Therefore, I am trying to compress the files with GZIP from within Mathematica, since they claim it is an option in the export function, which has a lot of bugs by the way.

Couldn't find any help the net after all the attempts following the documentation didn't pan out. I was wondering if one of our Mathematica enthusiasts can way in with some tips.

Comment: This question would be better served in [mathematica.stackexchange.com](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 6):

The compression happens automatically if the filename ends with ".gz"

So instead of

```
Export["file.h5", data]
```

Use

```
Export["file.h5.gz", data]
```

[List of available formats and their extension](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/CompressionAndArchiveFormats.html)

Comment: And to import it back: `Import["file.h5.gz", {"Datasets", "/Dataset1"}]`.